# Start a Linux daemon from Python

Tags: python, django, linux

Quick question,

I'm starting a linux daemon (motion) from a webpage using a python script inside Django. When I use the following:

```
def restartRecord():
    #restart the service
    config_file = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'recorder/config/motion.conf')
    p = subprocess.call(['motion', '-c', config_file])
    return True
```

It starts the daemon no problem, but it also ties up the port if I'm using running it from the django development server (port 8000). Is this the normal behaviour? - Why would starting the daemon tie up that port? I can test this by stopping the development server and trying to start it again.

Is there a better way to start this service?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Child processes inherit file descriptors, which includes network connections. A proper daemon will close all file descriptors inherited from the parent. Your daemon might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine under apache which is the main thing. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

`p = subprocess.call(['motion', '-c', config_file])` Is a synchronous call, meaning the page load will be blocked until "motion" quits (or fork-daemonizes itself.)

The Django development server is single threaded and hence will not serve any other requests while waiting for this request to succeed.

You may want to consider using the unix `start-stop-daemon` utility to wrap the call to motion.

Comment: in the motion config, it's set to run as a daemon. I can't seem to figure out how to do a start-stop using a customized motion configuration file, ie passing parameters. Any ideas?