# How to start a daemon with a Python written shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, service, daemon

I'm writing a basic bash shell replacement for my LFS, and they ask me to be able to start/stop a daemon in the LFS. I'm am new to Python, and managed to implement other commands like copy, move, etc in my shell, but starting daemons I don't know how, without a system call to a command like service from CentOS. Any help will be appreciated.
I searched and this articles didnt helped or didnt explained the method:

[Using Python to start a daemon and then return control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382339/using-python-to-start-a-daemon-and-then-return-control)

[Start a Linux daemon from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188721/start-a-linux-daemon-from-python)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the article you mention. I don't need to make a system call, I need it to be different than a syscall